# How to create custom json from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this,

```
df
col1    col2    col3
 A       1       2
 B       2       3
 C       4       5
 B       6       7
 B       9       10
 C       11      12
 A       13      14
```

I need to convert it to json format. When I converting using to_jon the outpput is like this,

```
{"col1":{"0":"A","1":"B","2":"C","3":"B","4":"B","5":"C","6":"A"},"col2": 
{"0":1,"1":2,"2":4,"3":6,"4":9,"5":11,"6":13},"col3": 
{"0":2,"1":3,"2":5,"3":7,"4":10,"5":12,"6":14}}
```

But the json I am looking for will look like,

```
{"A":{"col2":[1,13],"col3":[2,14]}, "B":{"col2":[2,6,9],"col3":[3,7,10]}, "C":{"col2": 
[4,11],"col3":[5,12]}}
```

I am looking for pandas shortcuts/ pythonic way to do this task efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `groupby+transpose`:

```
js = df.groupby('col1').agg(list).T.to_json()
#or df.pivot_table(columns='col1',aggfunc=list).to_json()
```

---

```
print(js)

{"A":{"col2":[1,13],"col3":[2,14]},"B":{"col2":[2,6,9],"col3":[3,7,10]},
 "C":{"col2":[4,11],"col3":[5,12]}}
```